# Api call in js function of angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to call api in javascript function like below but its not taking injected services (`subService`) or defined variables (`formData`)  in javascript function and getting error of `undefined addSub`. How should I call api in javascript function?

Please help and guide.

HTML

```
<button class="btn" (click)="initializePayment(item.id,item.price)">click here</button>
```

TS

```
 formData: any;
  loading: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private subService: SubService,
    ) { }

    initializePayment(sid,amount: number) {
        this.loading = true;
        const paymentHandler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
          key: this.stripeKey,
          locale: 'auto',
          token: function (stripeToken: any) {
            console.log({stripeToken});
            const sToken = stripeToken.id;
            this.formData = new FormData();
            this.formData.append('id', this.id);
            this.formData.append('s_id', sid);
            this.formData.append('stripeToken', sToken);
    
            this.subService.addSub(this.formData).subscribe(
              (response) => {
                this.loading = false;
                console.log('resp: ', response);
                if (response['status'] === true) {
                  this.notifyService.showSuccess(
                    'success!!',''
                  );
                  //window.location.reload();
                  this.router.navigate(['/user']);
                } else {
                  this.notifyService.showError(
                    'Something went wrong. Please try later!!!',''
                  );
                }
              },
              (error) => {
                this.notifyService.showError(
                  error,
                  'Oooops Something went wrong. Please try later!!'
                );
                this.loading = false;
              }
            );
            //alert('Stripe token generated!');
          }
        });
      
        paymentHandler.open({
          name: 'test',
          description: 'Upgrade',
          amount: amount * 100
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `function` assigned to `token` to use an arrow function instead.

```
token: (stripeToken: any) => {
            console.log({stripeToken});
            const sToken = stripeToken.id;
            this.formData = new FormData();
            this.formData.append('id', this.id);
            this.formData.append('s_id', sid);
            this.formData.append('stripeToken', sToken);
    
            this.subService.addSub(this.formData).subscribe(
              (response) => {
                this.loading = false;
                console.log('resp: ', response);
                if (response['status'] === true) {
                  this.notifyService.showSuccess(
                    'success!!',''
                  );
                  //window.location.reload();
                  this.router.navigate(['/user']);
                } else {
                  this.notifyService.showError(
                    'Something went wrong. Please try later!!!',''
                  );
                }
              },
              (error) => {
                this.notifyService.showError(
                  error,
                  'Oooops Something went wrong. Please try later!!'
                );
                this.loading = false;
              }
            );
            //alert('Stripe token generated!');
          }
        })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was wondering what changes should I make inside function but your change made it easier. Learned lesson. thanks.